# Bulk copy program Insert 4 millions records into new table

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

In powershell I would like to use Bulk copy to export and then import data from one table to another in the same database. The DB server is not local on my dev machine so I am using the /S as the Database instance name. The error that I am getting is A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options not sure what I have incorrect with the command. I am using Windows Authentication for studio.

```
PS C:\Users\dev> $psCommand = "bcp $($db).$($schema).$($table) out $path /S$($server) /t /c, -T"

PS C:\Users\dev> Invoke-Expression $psCommand
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @SeanLange is that the correct command for using a Windows Authentication SQL server connection?